# Matlab, interpolate non-square matrix keeping aspect-ratio

Tags: matlab, matrix, aspect-ratio, interpolation

I have a matrix with dimension 27x4, now I want to interpolate the matrix and plot it with the same aspect ratio. I've been using interp2 but since it fills in values in between existing ones after each step the matrix grows in both dimension 2*n-1, which results in the height growing faster than the width.
Is there a method to interpolate a matrix filling the new matrix only with interpolated values without the original ones, to say get one with both dimensions doubled?
The only method I could think of, is to interpolate with interp2 to a higher degree and then pick out values, but this would be highly inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`interp2` should work fine, it must be how you are define the last 2 parameter. Try this:

```
Z = rand(4,27);
x = 1:27;
y = 1:4;
[X, Y] = meshgrid(x, y)

xi = linspace(1, 27, 1000);
yi = linspace(1, 4, 1000 * (4/27)); % The 4/27 here is what ensures you keep the aspect ratio
[XI, YI] = meshgrid(xi, yi);

ZI = interp2(X,Y,Z,XI,YI);
```

Check the aspect ratios

```
size(ZI,1) / size(ZI,2)

ans =

    0.1480

size(Z,1) / size(Z,2)

ans =

    0.1481
```

But basically all you need to ensure is that the aspect ratio of `xi` and `yi` in my code above match your original. Pretty easy to generalize as well.

Comment: X and Y is flipped and then YI has to be transposed, at least in my Matlab version, but else it worked like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user2366412 Sure, please mark it as solved by clicking on the outlined tick mark in the top left of the solution